# WPF button not centering Unicode characters

Tags: c#, wpf, unicode

I have a couple of buttons in my WPF application that have Unicode characters in them.

I.E.

```
Button x:Name="Backspace" Content="&#8592;" FontSize="50" Click="Backspace_Click"
```

The ← inside the button renders just fine... but only when the button is above a certain height! As soon as the button gets too small, it suddenly will stop centering the ← vertically and it will go off the button (as you can see, it still isn't perfectly centering the ← even when the button is larger)

[image: No good!] [image]

Setting the button's `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Center` doesn't help, and setting it to `Stretch` causes the ← to move up as the button gets taller. Horizontally, the ← is centered just fine.

This happens with all the unicode characters I've used. Making the font size smaller will cause it to happen when the button is smaller and vice versa.

Is there anything I can do? Maybe using a custom content template for the button to make the unicode character bigger, rather than using a large font size? Is the unicode character not reporting the correct height for its glyph or something? If I can't get this to work, I'll probably just end up shoving an image of the unicode character into the button, which would be... unfortunate.

Comment: notice the height is the same.  looks like your margins are giving you trouble. you should post more code

Comment: sorry I ment the height ABOVE the arrow

Comment: I noticed the height is the same too. No margins involved, the button is in a grid with cell height * and width *, and that grid is in a user control that's in another grid also with * cell width and height

Comment: This can be tested by creating a blank window and putting a button with a unicode character in it. Resizing the button you can see the character move down in the button when it gets small enough. This seems to be the default behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Padding .. That should do the trick

```
<Button x:Name="Backspace" Content="&#8592;" FontSize="50" Width="100" Height="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0,-10,0,0"/>
```

Comment: That actually works pretty well! Don't know why `Padding` didn't cross my mind. It still moves once the button gets small enough but it'll do the trick for now.

Comment: @TranquilMarmot it did not cross your mind because it's just a hacky (some kind of hardcoded) way of solving it.

Comment: @KingKing Yeah I would definitely prefer a more elegant solution; padding is sort of just a pacifier for now.